# DocX looping table for unknown amount of rows

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, loops, novacode-docx

I have recently installed DocX for asp.net and have encountered an issue for create a loop for an unknown amount of rows.

I am creating a report for users coming from a SQL server. A section of this is to do with history, in the database for each report there is a different amount of rows for each report that is created. is there a way to create a loop or similar to output this unknown amount of rows?

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
{
    t.Rows[i].Cells[0].Paragraphs.First().Append(Data from SQL);
}

t.Alignment = Alignment.center;
t.Design = TableDesign.TableGrid;

t.Rows[0].Cells[0].Paragraphs.First().Append("Update Date");
t.Rows[0].Cells[1].Paragraphs.First().Append("Update By");
t.Rows[0].Cells[2].Paragraphs.First().Append("Code");
t.Rows[0].Cells[3].Paragraphs.First().Append("Status/Description");
t.Rows[0].Cells[4].Paragraphs.First().Append("System");

t.Rows[1].Cells[0].Paragraphs.First().Append("update_date");
t.Rows[1].Cells[1].Paragraphs.First().Append("update_by");
t.Rows[1].Cells[2].Paragraphs.First().Append("codes");
t.Rows[1].Cells[3].Paragraphs.First().Append("status");
t.Rows[1].Cells[4].Paragraphs.First().Append("system");
```

`t.rows[0].Cells[0-4]` are headers the rest will be coming from the database.
Is there an better way rather than using DocX?

`t.Rows[1].Cells[0-4]` is needed to come from the database (headers of table in SQL) This is frustrating me, I have never been good with loops

Thank you for your time.

Comment: About your code above: are you overwriting the values set by the for loop with hard coded values below? Why?

Comment: The loop was meant to replace the rows below the header from database. I've never been good with loops. Thank you

Comment: is your problem solved?

Comment: I have changed the code and data is not filling in from database only hard coded text

Comment: @bert_148 how are you accessing data from database and what are you storing it in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of the code. I am using a class to place all of my database information.

```
List<Education> eduList = aDoc.getAppEdu(aDoc.AppID);
if (refList.Count < 0)
{
      appQue.AppendLine("Applicant did not supply Educational Background information." + Environment.NewLine).Bold();
}
else
{
     foreach (Education ed in eduList)
     {
          Novacode.Table tblEdu = doc.AddTable(6, 1);                                      
          tblEdu.AutoFit = AutoFit.Contents;   
          tblEdu.Rows[0].Cells[0].Paragraphs.First().Append("Education").Bold().FontSize(13);  
            tblEdu.Rows[1].Cells[0].Paragraphs.First().Append("* School Name: ");                          tblEdu.Rows[1].Cells[0].Paragraphs.First().Append(ed.SchoolName).Bold(); ;
            tblEdu.Rows[2].Cells[0].Paragraphs.First().Append("* City: ");
            tblEdu.Rows[2].Cells[0].Paragraphs.First().Append(ed.City).Bold();
            tblEdu.Rows[2].Cells[0].Paragraphs.First().Append("* State: ");
            tblEdu.Rows[2].Cells[0].Paragraphs.First().Append(ed.EduState).Bold();
            tblEdu.Rows[2].Cells[0].Paragraphs.First().Append("* Zip: ");
            tblEdu.Rows[2].Cells[0].Paragraphs.First().Append(ed.Zip).Bold();
            tblEdu.Rows[3].Cells[0].Paragraphs.First().Append("* From: ");
            tblEdu.Rows[3].Cells[0].Paragraphs.First().Append(ed.SStartScho).Bold();
            tblEdu.Rows[3].Cells[0].Paragraphs.First().Append("* To: ");
            tblEdu.Rows[3].Cells[0].Paragraphs.First().Append(ed.SEndScho).Bold();
            tblEdu.Rows[4].Cells[0].Paragraphs.First().Append("* Did you graduate? ");
            string grad = "No";
            if (ed.Graduate == true)
            {
                grad = "Yes";
            }                                                     
            tblEdu.Rows[4].Cells[0].Paragraphs.First().Append(grad).Bold();
            tblEdu.Rows[5].Cells[0].Paragraphs.First().Append("* Diploma/Degree: ");               tblEdu.Rows[5].Cells[0].Paragraphs.First().Append(ed.Degree).Bold();                                                            
            doc.InsertTable(tblEdu);
            appQue = doc.InsertParagraph();
     }
}
```